# Cron Schedule for a job that runs every minute from 8 am to 7:30 pm

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I can't figure out how to create a job that ends at a specific hour and minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break your cronjob into two, it would look like:

```
* 8-19 * * * command
0-30/1 19 * * * command
```

first line runs every minute from 8-19, and second line every minute from 19-19:30.

Answer (score 1):

Cron triggers are not quite suitable for these types of schedules. If you do not insist on using a Cron trigger, I recommend that you check the [Daily Time Interval](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.html) trigger that is designed for use-cases such as yours. I am attaching a screenshot of a Daily Time Interval Trigger configuration for your use-case.

[image: Sample Daily Time Interval Trigger]